# jqgrid - change column header name automatically according to the width

Tags: jquery-plugins, jqgrid, header, calculated-columns, ellipsis

in my site , i have a jqgrid table.

by default, the names of the columns (header) is longer than the width for column, because that i set the name with an ellipsis.

however, when resizing the column, the short name with ellipsis stays.

how can i get it work automatic  ,
like the ellipsis should disappear and change to the full name when there is enough space, when the user is expanding the column.

thanks

Comment: There are alternative solutions of your problem. Could you post an example of your jqGrid definition and the code which you use to produce the names with ellipsis? Which web browser you use? IE6? Why `autowidth` option is not good enough for you? Probably an exaple answers to the most questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an event handler after the resizing finishes to reset the names.  How are you storing / changing the names?  If they're in an array, you can add a function like:

```
var columnNames = ['first', 'second', 'third'];    
$("#mygrid").jqGrid({
   ...
   resizeStop: function(newwidth, index){ 
      jQuery("#mygrid").jqGrid('setLabel',index,columnNames[index]);
   },
   ...
});
```

Comment: thank you about the answer, but i need something automatically , in this solution i need to calculate the width and see how much characters it get in ... , i want to see if possible to declare one long header and the display is according to size width